# Is it possible to use an input to disable Angular animation

Tags: angular, animation

I am developing a library which contains an overlay (using Angular CDK), I use an animation to show and hide the overlay.

I want to provide an input to the component to disable the animation, I checked Angular docs but there is no mention of such use case,  my component looks like this:

```js
@Component({
  host: {
    '[@dialog]': '{ value: state }',
    '(@dialog.done)': 'onAnimationDone($event)',
  },
  selector: 'lightbox',
  templateUrl: './lightbox.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  animations: [dialogAnimation]
})
export class Lightbox {
   @Input() disableAnimation: boolean;
}
```

Is there a way to make this as an option without using the `AnimationBuilder`?

If `AnimationBuilder` is the only way, How can I simulate `:enter` and `:leave` animations?

Comment: You can use the events (mouseover) and (mouseout) events, this can help you trigger the :enter and :leave. But make sure you add the listeners to the parent element, and not the child

Comment: @SARANSURYA you did not understand what I am asking, nor you seem to know Angular! its ok :)

Comment: I have currently started to work on angular recently, So maybe I did not get your question right enough. Is it that you want to disable the default animations that the Angular CDK overlay uses ? I took it in a way that you wanted to start and end those animations, so that was that older comment, If you can put it in a codeSandbox, it will be helpful also. If you did find the answer please do update it here, that will help others including me :)

Comment: @SARANSURYA No worries, just ignore the question at this stage :)